# Accented math operator

Tags: symbols, math-operators, accents

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{décalage}

\begin{document}
\(\shift x\)
\end{document}
```

It produces the correct result but throws the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \' invalid in math mode on input line 11.
```

Is there a situation where I might get a wrong result? I underestand
that the problem is that the accent commands are different in text and math
mode, and this is the cause of the warning. So I tried `\(décalage\)` and the
letter `é` is upright instead of italic.
Are any such case for the operators?

Comment: You can use `\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{\text{décalage}}`

Comment: Then the operator will have the same font as the surrounding text, which isn't good (in theorems for example).

Comment: I was about to say the same thing: `\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{\textup{décalage}}` is better.

Comment: Ow, well observed. `\textup` should be better.

Comment: then, it wouldn't work in a `\bfseries` context :)

Comment: Well observed too. (:-)  With `\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{\textnormal{décalage}}` we should be OK, though.

Comment: this one seems to work. Apart from getting rid of the warning, is there any reason to use this solution over just `\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{décalage}`?

Comment: It’s a long story: try to search for “\text \mathrm” on this site, and you’ll see.  TeXnically, `\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{shift}` (say) appends to the current math list *five* `\mathord` atoms, each containing in its nucleus a letter in the `operator` font (cmr, in bare LaTeX without packages)—“s”, “h”, etc.  The other alternative appends a much more complex constuction (a `\mathchoice`), that contains the whole word, as embedded *text*, in four distinct variants for the four math styles (display, text, …), so it is actually much more cumbersome too.

Comment: Wow, I don't understand half your comment. I'll try and search in the site for your suggestion.

Comment: The short version of the story is: use simply `\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{myOpName}`, unless you have some very special reason not to.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are in math mode, use `\acute` instead of `\'` or a precomposed `é`.

This works:

```
\DeclareMathOperator\shift{d\acute ecalage}
```